# How To Calculate Total Minute LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

I want to calculate total minute with my data.

> [{"id":3,"zone_id":21,"created_at":"2017-06-22
>   09:49:33","updated_at":"2017-06-22
>   09:49:33","deviceNo":"ogrv", "type": "0" },{"id":4,"zone_id":22,"created_at":"2017-06-22
>   09:50:09","updated_at":"2017-06-22
>   09:50:09","deviceNo":"ogrv", "type": "1"},{"id":5,"zone_id":21,"created_at":"2017-06-22
>   09:50:35","updated_at":"2017-06-22
>   09:50:35","deviceNo":"ogrv", "type": "0"},{"id":6,"zone_id":22,"created_at":"2017-06-22
>   11:51:52","updated_at":"2017-06-22
>   11:51:52","deviceNo":"ogrv", "type": "1"},{"id":7,"zone_id":21,"created_at":"2017-06-22
>   11:54:57","updated_at":"2017-06-22
>   11:54:57","deviceNo":"ogrv", "type": "0"},{"id":8,"zone_id":22,"created_at":"2017-06-22
>   11:57:17","updated_at":"2017-06-22 11:57:17","deviceNo":"ogrv", "type": "1"}]

if type 0 will come I will start to calculate until type 1. How can I calculate it with php?

---

Each type means different actions so when different actions came I need the calculate minutes between this 2 data.

For example First Data came with type 0 that means user is inside then second data is came with type 1 and that means user is not inside. I need the calculate total minutes between this datas.

Comment: updated I wrongly selected that sorry about it

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Unclear question..

Comment: @kupendra updated Question I gave an example to being clear.

Comment: You want to calculate time difference for each case when you get transition on type value from `0 -> 1 ` or `1->0` Am I right ?

Comment: @SagarGautam yes thats correct

Comment: @MuratKaya just with sql query it's difficult but using some loops you can do it

Comment: @SagarGautam how can I do that  will you give me some example block?

Comment: I have added, take a moment to view it. I have assumed you can calculate difference between two date times.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this, May help you

If you have database table model as Model,

```
$data = Model::all()->toArray();
$diff_array = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($data)-1; $i++){
    $first = $data[$i];
    $second = $data[$i+1];
    if($first['type']==0 && second['type'] == 1){

        // Calculate difference between $first['created_at] and $second['created_at'] as $diff_time
        // you can parse string date using Carbon and calculate diffrence.

        array_push($diff_array,$diff_time);

    }
    else if($first['type']==1 && second['type'] == 0){

        // Calculate difference between $first['created_at] and $second['created_at'] as $diff_time

        array_push($diff_array,$diff_time);
    }   
}

// dump the array to view differences
dd($diff_array);
```